# JavaScript regex match [[quote][/quote]]

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var quote = 'some text here [[quote=bob]This is some text bob wrote[/quote]] other text here';
```

I'm trying to get `[[quote=bob]This is some text bob wrote[/quote]]`.

I was using:
    `match(/[[quote=(.*?)](.*?)[/quote]]/)[1]`

but it gives me `some text here [[quote=bob]This is some text bob wrote[/quot`

Comment: `quote.match(/\[\[quote=(.*?)](.*?)\[\/quote]]/)[0]`

Comment: Be aware of [You can't parse (X)HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630). It may be applicable to your case too, if your language is complex enough.

Comment: @Oriol - I'm not seeing any HTML in that string.

Comment: @j08691 Yes, but that seems suspiciously close to html. I only wanted to warn, just in case.

Comment: I'm taking text and translating it into html - just like people see on many phpbb forums

Comment: The same caveats apply to bbcode. Changing the brackets from angled to square doesn't change the syntactic complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var quote = 'some text here [[quote=bob]This is some text bob wrote[/quote]] other text here';

console.log( quote.match(/(\[\[quote=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/quote\]\])/) );
// [1] => "[[quote=bob]This is some text bob wrote[/quote]]"
// [2] => "bob"
// [3] => "This is some text bob wrote"
```

Comment: Using `.*` here is not safe as I stated in my answer. Regex will find the longest possible match and so using a different string I get bad results : `'some text here [[quote=bob]This is some text bob wrote[/quote]] other text here[/quote]]'.match(/.*(\[\[quote=.*?\].*?\[\/quote\]\])/); ` gives : `["some text here [[quote=bob]This is some text bob wrote[/quote]]","[[quote=bob]This is some text bob wrote[/quote]]"]`

Comment: @Johnride `.*` does that, not `.*?`.

Comment: That's one I didn't know about. `?` turns `+` and `*` into non-greedy matches. Nice one. Here take my upvote.

Comment: This still fails on nested quotes, e.g. this: "[[quote=foo]some text here [[quote=bob]This is some text bob wrote[/quote]] other text here[/quote]]" (see http://regexr.com/39sa0 for a live example)

Comment: @JesseWatZ Then it becomes much less straigthforward. Using recursive backrefs or something like that is required. I like regexes, it's a world of ever-ending improving and learning. Mine works a little better with nested quotes but has to be used recursively deleting the previous match. http://regexr.com/39sa3. Mine fails if the quote contains a [ though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `[` is a reserved character in regular expressions so you must escape it to use it as a "regular" character.

Here is a start for you, this will match [quote=bob] from your variable quote.

`quote.match(/\[quote=[a-z]*\]/)`

Here is the complete, correct and safe version.

```
string.match(/\[quote=[a-z]*\]([^\[]*)\[\/quote\]/)
```

Which will return the proper string including the surrounding [quote] tags as first result and only the inner string as second result.

I also used the [a-z] character class as you don't want to match anything after the `=` character.